# Ошибка установки статуса vk_api python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, vknet

Вроде всё нормально,пытаюсь запустить код...

```
import time
import datetime
import vk_api

def auth_handler():
    """ При двухфакторной аутентификации вызывается эта функция.
    """

    # Код двухфакторной аутентификации
    key = input("Enter authentication code: ")
    # Если: True - сохранить, False - не сохранять.
    remember_device = True

    return key, remember_device


def main():
    """ Пример обработки двухфакторной аутентификации """

    login, password = '*******', '******'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
        login, password,
        # функция для обработки двухфакторной аутентификации
        auth_handler=auth_handler
    )

    try:
        def countdown(stop):
            while True:
                difference = stop - datetime.datetime.now()
                count_hours, rem = divmod(difference.seconds, 3600)
                count_minutes, count_seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
                if difference.days == 0 and count_hours == 0 and count_minutes == 0 and count_seconds == 0:
                    print("end")
                    break
                vk_session.auth()
                vk_session.method("status.set",f"{str(difference.days)}:{str(count_hours)}:{str(count_minutes)}:{str(count_seconds)}")
                time.sleep(1)


        end_time = datetime.datetime(9999, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        countdown(end_time)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return
main()
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zederbreys/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "/home/zederbreys/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "/home/zederbreys/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/zederbreys/Рабочий стол/time.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zederbreys/Рабочий стол/time.py", line 42, in main
    countdown(end_time)
  File "/home/zederbreys/Рабочий стол/time.py", line 37, in countdown
    vk_session.method("status.set",f"{str(difference.days)}:{str(count_hours)}:{str(count_minutes)}:{str(count_seconds)}")
  File "/home/zederbreys/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 585, in method
    values = values.copy() if values else {}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Если кто сталкивался с подобным напишите решение ошибки.

**Для тех кто будет писать исп. другую библиотеку,мне нужна именно эта так как в этой я знаю как пройти двойную аутентификацию**

Comment: Перечитайте внимательно документацию этой библиотеки и узнайте, как правильно вызывать методы с её использованием

Comment: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/404d83e678ecc3c755c0271d095e71a644cb4a09/vk_api/vk_api.py#L562 - описание метода `method` в исходниках либы.

Answer (score 0):

Так как я писал код поздно сразу не заметил ошибку,если же у кого будет такая же проблема то вот её решение:
в данном случаи vk просит нас вернуть ей текст в формате json и просто так написав текст vk не годится.

пример:

левый случай:

```
vk_session.method("status.set", {"text": "hi"})
```

мой случай:

```
vk_session.method("status.set",{"text":f"{str(difference.days)}:{str(count_hours)}:{str(count_minutes)}:{str(count_seconds)}"})
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не json; во-вторых, на ВК всё отправляется в формате application/x-www-form-urlencoded или multipart/form-data